# Hibernate criteria API querying inheritance issue

Tags: java, hibernate

Lets say that class 'X' is mapped to table 'X' class 'A' is mapped to Table 'A' and Class 'B is mapped to table 'B'.

Table X Structure:(X_ID, some other columns
Table A Structure:(A_Id,X_Id, some other columns)
Table B Structure:(A_Id, some other columns)...Table B also has A_Id

**Class 'B' extends class 'A'.** We have the mapping files for both of them as:

**Class 'A' Parent Mapping file:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'A')
@Inheritance(stratergy=InheritanceType.Joined)
public abstract class A {
@Id @Clumns(name = "A_Id)
@GeneratedValue
protected Long aId;
-- some more A specific fields
}
```

**Class 'B' Mapping file:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name= 'B')
Public class B extends A{
---- B specific fields
}
```

Now, I have a SQL Query as below that I need to write using hibernate criteria API.

```
select * from X
INNER JOIN A 
ON X.id = A.id
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id
where B.name = 'XYZ'
   and B.Sex = 'M'
```

I have come up with:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(x.class, "x");
                    .createAlias("x.a", "a")
                    .createAlias("a.b", "b")          
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("b.sex", "M"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("b.name", "XYZ"));
```

But, if we check the mapping file, there is no direct reference of B in A. Hence hibernate throws out "B not related to A" entity.

Is there any way this inheritance can be mapped in query crteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is-a A. So you don't need to make any join between A and B. Hibernate does that for you:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(x.class, "x");
                    .createAlias("x.a", "b")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("b.sex", "M"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("b.name", "XYZ"));
```

Comment: thanks...worked like  a charm...i should have known it earlier...good to know it now..